# warning MSB8065: specified output has not been created

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cmake-custom-command

Any "custom build" generated with Cmake is not having the output file generated.

Apparently the output directories are lowercase.

This only happens on ASUS computer with Ryzem 9 7950X

I have no idea what else to do to resolve this issue and get back to work.

Warnings

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\atomic\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\clog\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\ghost\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\guardedalloc\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\libmv\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\memutil\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\opencolorio\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\opensubdiv\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\mikktspace\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\eigen\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\sky\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\audaspace\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\dualcon\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\iksolver\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\itasc\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\rigidbody\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\utfconv\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\openvdb\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\quadriflow\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\intern\ffmpeg\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\curve_fit_nd\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\rangetree\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\wcwidth\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\bullet2\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\draco\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\draco\draco\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\lzo\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\lzma\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\clew\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\cuew\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "D:\BlenderDev\x64-Debug\CMakeFiles\b26398152121886241ff45e21d2215c8\generate.stamp.rule" succeeded, but specified output "d:\blenderdev\x64-debug\extern\hipew\cmakefiles\generate.stamp" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
.
.
.
```

I tried:

- Reinstall Visual Studio Community 2022
- Change file permissions
- Update/Reinstall CMake
- Clean Solution
- Rebuild (Debug/Release)
- Ninja builder
- Update motherboard BIOS

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a reason for these warnings!

The source files were copied when the computer had a manually set date that was above the current date.

Later, the date was corrected automatically.

This caused confusion in the timestamps and hence the errors.

One solution is to correct the dates of source files.